# backbone.js having trouble with fetch() on a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

Warning: Code is in Coffeescript. I hope that's ok.

I have a model, `Song`, a collection `Songs`, and a view `SongsView`. Here it is:

```
SONG_TEMPLATE = '''
  <table>
  {{#if songs.length }}
    {{#each songs}}
        <tr><td>{{ this.name }}</td><td>{{ this.duration }}</td></tr>
    {{/each}}
  {{/if}}
  </table>
'''

$ ->
  class Song extends Backbone.Model
    parse: (response) ->
      console.log "model parsing #{response}"
    #

  class Songs extends Backbone.Collection
    initialize: ->
      @model = Song
      @url   = "/songs/data"

    parse: (response) ->
      console.log "collection parsing"
      console.log response

  # This works. The JSON here was grabbed right out of the XHR response I got from the server and pasted into my code.

  songs = new Songs(
    [
      {"name":"Stray Cat Strut","rating":4,"duration":3},
      {"name":"Chinatown","rating":2,"duration":4.2},
      {"name":"Sultans of Swing","rating":3,"duration":5.4},
      {"name":"Pride & Joy","rating":3,"duration":3}
    ]
    )

  # This fails. It should be exactly the same as the above code, and indeed, the collection parsing takes place.
  # However, the view renders nothing.

  # songs = new Songs
  # songs.fetch()

  class SongsView extends Backbone.View
    initialize: ->
      @model = Song
      @render()

    render: =>
      console.log "render"
      console.log @collection
      template = Handlebars.compile(SONG_TEMPLATE)
      @template = template(songs: @collection.toJSON())
      console.log "template: #{@template}"
      $('#song-list').html @template

  songView = new SongsView(collection: songs)
```

The issue I'm having is that there is some subtle difference between initializing `songs` from the JSON string and allowing backbone to populate it using `fetch()`. The object looks ok in the script debug window, but no joy.

So, what's going on here and am I sort of on the right track?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetch is an asynchronous method, this means that when you render your view, the data has not been retrieved, but when you write it manually, the data is there.  The general way to do this is to bind the reset trigger that gets called by fetch to the render method.

```
class SongsView extends Backbone.View
  initialize: ->
    @model = Song
    @collection.bind("reset", @render)
  render: =>
    console.log "render"
    console.log @collection
    template = Handlebars.compile(SONG_TEMPLATE)
    @template = template(songs: @collection.toJSON())
    console.log "template: #{@template}"
    $('#song-list').html @template
```

You should probably more your songs.fetch below where you instantiate your view too.

Comment: Still not getting it to work. The "fetch" event this I've bound does not trigger this.render(). @collection is a Songs object, but of course is empty in the initializer. Did I miss something -- is there some great reference material that would make this all obvious to me? (d'oh!)

Comment: Please post your code.  The official docs has worked well for me.  There are also a couple screencasts on http://peepcode.com There is also a good tutorial at http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/03/03/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon.html

Comment: It's here: https://gist.github.com/1448858. I did move the fetch into my view initialize function. It still doesn't call render(). I even tried delegateEvents() on the off chance that an event delegation problem was in play.

Comment: Oops, I meant to bind to the reset trigger from the fetch method!  Try this:  https://gist.github.com/1449022  The backbone docs have a list of the triggers that are sent.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. This does trigger the render function, but the collection `@collection` which is simply `this.collection` is still empty with a length of zero. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Please post the contents of your JSON response, I have a feeling that might be the issue.

Comment: Ohhhh. It was a stupid mistake. I put a `parse()` function in my collection for debugging purposes and it didn't return anything meaningful. Sheesh. Thanks for being so patient.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Gazler, the problem is that `fetch` is asynchronous. If you want to use Gazler's solution, be aware that the collection's `fetch` method no longer triggers the `reset` event by default. Therefore, you'll need to have the collection explicitly trigger the `reset` event:

```
my_collection.fetch({reset: true})
```

Another solution to solving this is using jQuery deferreds to display the view once the results have been fetched. More one using deferreds to manage view display when fetching data asynchronously: http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/04/01/using-jquery-promises-to-render-backbone-views-after-fetching-data/

And waiting for multiple asynchronous data sources to return: http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/04/02/rendering-a-view-after-multiple-async-functions-return-using-promises/